# Inequality : $(a^3+3)(b^3+6)(c^3+12)>k(a+b+c)^3$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, holder-inequality

Find the largest integer $k$ such that

$$(a^3+3)(b^3+6)(c^3+12)>k(a+b+c)^3$$

for all positive real numbers $a, b, c$.

My attempt :

By Holder inequality, $(a^3+1+2)(2+b^3+4)(4+8+c^3)\geq(\sqrt[3]{8}a+\sqrt[3]{8}b+\sqrt[3]{8}c)^3$

$\Leftrightarrow(a^3+3)(b^3+6)(c^3+12)\geq8(a+b+c)^3$

There is no equality hold.

so $(a^3+3)(b^3+6)(c^3+12)(a+b+c)^3>8(a+b+c)^3$

Comment: I think this is a good argument. May I recommend adding "proof-verification" tag to the question?

Comment: @rtybase, Thank you, "proof-verification" tag has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality should be for $(a,1,\sqrt[3]2)||(\sqrt[3]2,b,\sqrt[4]4)||(\sqrt[3]4,2,c),$ which is impossible.

Let $a_1+a_2=3$, $b_1+b_2=6$, $c_1+c_2=12$, $b_1c_1=a_1c_2=a_2b_2$, where $a_i\geq0$, $b_i\geq0$ and $c_i\geq0$.

Thus, for the equality occurring after using Holder we need 
 $$\left(a,\sqrt[3]{a_1},\sqrt[3]{a_2}\right)||\left(\sqrt[3]{b_1},b,\sqrt[3]{b_2}\right)||\left(\sqrt[3]{c_1},\sqrt[3]{c_2},c\right),$$
which is very ugly:
$k_{max}=8.093...$ for $(a,b,c)=(0.904...,1.368...,2.297...)$,

but it says $8$ is a maximum possible integer value, for which our inequality is true

and $(0.904,1.368,2.297)$ is a counterexample for all integer $k>8$.

By the way, there is a counterexample, which is a bit of better: $$(a,b,c)=(1,2,2).$$

In the exam you apply your proof for $k=8$ and for $k\geq9$ you write:

The equality $$(a^3+3)(b^3+6)(c^3+12)\geq k(a+b+c)^3$$
is wrong. $(1,2,2)$ is the counterexample.

Comment: @carat I added something. See now please.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I was a bit confused. Thank you very much for your helpful explanation.